# VS Code no me ejecutar un programa porque dice que no encuentra una imagen que puse usando Tkinter en Python

Tags: python, tkinter, vscode, sublimetext3, spyder

¿qué tal?

Empecé a programar en Pyhton hace unos 3 meses aproximadamente, y ahora estoy haciendo interfaces gráficas usando Tkinter.

Cuando quiero agregar una imagen, VSCode no me ejecuta el programa, y me dice: "_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "avion.png": no such file or directory". Cuando ejecuto el programa con Sublime Text 3 o con Spyder, si me lo ejecuta. Asi que debe ser un problema de VSCode.

Si alguien sabe por qué pasa esto con VSCode, le agradecería.

Acá abajo dejo mi código,

Saludos!

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

root.title("Check Buttons")

playa = IntVar()
montana = IntVar()
ciudad = IntVar()

def opciones_viaje():

    opcion_elegida=""

    if playa.get()==1:
        opcion_elegida+=" Playa "
    if montana.get() == 1:
        opcion_elegida += " Montaña "
    if ciudad.get() == 1:
        opcion_elegida += " Ciudad "
    
    texto_final.config(text=opcion_elegida)


foto=PhotoImage(file="avion.png")
Label(root, image=foto).pack()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

Label(frame, text="Elige destinos", width=50).pack()

boton1=Checkbutton(frame, text="Playa", variable=playa, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=opciones_viaje).pack(anchor="w")
boton2=Checkbutton(frame, text="Montaña", variable=montana, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=opciones_viaje).pack(anchor="w")
boton3=Checkbutton(frame, text="Ciudad", variable=ciudad, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=opciones_viaje).pack(anchor="w")


texto_final=Label(frame)
texto_final.pack()





root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Alberto, ¿sabes cómo hacer para que cuando ejecute dentro de VS aparezca dentro de la raíz? Claramente ese es el problema, ya que me lo ejecuta bien en todos lados, excepto dentro de VS.

Comment: La cosa es hacer que sea automatico, y no tener que escribir eso ca vez que quiera ejecutar dentro de VS